# Diffeomorphism from level sets onto spheres

Tags: differential-topology, morse-theory

I am just learning Morse theory. I apologize if the solution to the following question is well-known.

For a Morse function $f(x):\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, if the level set $f^{-1}(c)$ only contains regular points, is $f^{-1}(c)$ always diffeomorphic to a collection of $(n-1)$-spheres? If no, what conditions can make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for example if $f(x) = \langle a,x\rangle$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{O\}$ then  $\nabla f(x) = a \neq 0$ so that any point is regular but the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ is an affine hyperplane.

What you can say is that **if**  $f^{-1}(c_0) \simeq \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ for some $c_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ has no critical points ($f$ smooth). Then the inverse image of any point $c_1$ such that $f^{-1}([c_0,c_1])$ is compact is  diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ (it is also smoothly isotopic).
So for example if $f$ is proper then the fiber of any point in the image will be diffeomerphic to $f^{-1}(c_0)$.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to consider $f$ that has at least one critical point.

Comment: The point of the statement is that if $f^{-1}([c_0,c_1])$ is compact and do not contain critical points then the fiber of $c_0$ and the fiber of $c_1$ are diffeomorphic. This doesn't exclude the possibility to have other critical points.

Comment: I have seen results similar to what you said in some textbooks. The question is, when does $f^{-1}(c_0)\simeq \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ happen.

Comment: Consider a critical point $p$ of $f$ of index $0$, then in some neighbourhood of $p$, $U$  (by Morse's lemma) it holds that $f=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ up to diffeomorphism. If $f^{-1}(y)\subset U$ and $y$ is regular then the fiber is an  $n-1$-sphere.

Comment: ($p$ must be also not degenerate in order to apply Morse's Lemma)

Comment: Thanks. Does a more general result exist? For example, does the conclusion hold if we know $f^{-1}(c)$ is compact and $f$ has no degenerate critical points?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. But it can be interesting.  I suggest you to ask it in a separate question. By the way, if you think that your original question have been answered it is a good practice to accept the best answer, otherwise you could also wait for others  answers.  Have a nice day.

Comment: @billj: This is rarely true. If $c$ is slightly more than a local minimum, or slightly less than a local maximum, there is a connected component which is a sphere. I suggest you draw some examples.